# Fine train a convnet on difficult data only?

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I use a convnet to classify two types of objects: class A and B.

I created the data set myself and have around 1000 examples per class. Some are really obvious and clear, some others are very difficult.

My question is: After the training, is it a good idea to retrain the model just on the data that are not correctly classified ?

Fore example, by taking 50% of the examples that are the least correctly classify and retrain for some epochs on them only. My intuition is that it would help the network focus on non-obvious features that could have been learnt during the first training phase .

EDIT: I am an idiot. A training on a subset of the data will necessarily result in an increase of the loss for the rest of the data (except if there are some magic tricks I don't know about). The only good solution is to design a custom loss function that fits my needs for the first training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot. A training on a subset of the data will necessarily result in an increase of the loss for the rest of the data (except if there are some magic tricks I don't know about). The only good solution is to design a custom loss function that fits my needs for the first training.